# How to save my input values to text file with ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, fs

I have contact form with three inputs fields and I want to save input values into text file when users click on the button.
How can I do that.. ?
Can I take example ?

My code:

```
import React, { } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import MapContainer from "./Map";
import { Button, ButtonGroup } from '@material-ui/core';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      phone: '',
      message: ''
    };
  }

  TextFile = () => {
    const element = document.createElement("a");
    const file = new Blob([document.getElementById('message').value], {type: 'text/plain'});
    element.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    element.download = "myFile.txt";
    document.body.appendChild(element); // Required for this to work in FireFox
    element.click();
  }

  handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    axios({
      method: "POST", 
      url:"http://localhost:3000", 
      data:  this.state
    }).then((response)=>{
      if (response.data.status === 'success'){
        alert("Message Sent."); 
        this.resetForm()
      }else if(response.data.status === 'fail'){
        alert("Message failed to send.")
      }
    })
  }

  resetForm(){

     this.setState({name: '', phone: '', message: ''})
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">

          <span className="Logo">ХAРДУЕРЕН И СОФТУЕРЕН СЕРВИЗ</span>
          <br />
          <p><img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" /><span className="LogoBlink">PIZHINGSTONE</span><img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" /></p>

          <Container>
            <Row>
              <Col>

                    <ButtonGroup color="secondary" aria-label="outlined primary button group">
                      <Button  className="button">софтуерни инсталации</Button>
                    </ButtonGroup>

                  <ButtonGroup color="secondary" aria-label="outlined primary button group">
                      <Button className="button">хардуерна поддръжка</Button>
                    </ButtonGroup>

                  <ButtonGroup color="secondary" aria-label="outlined primary button group">
                      <Button className="button">отдалечен достъп</Button>
                    </ButtonGroup>

                  <ButtonGroup color="secondary" aria-label="outlined primary button group">
                      <Button className="button">ремонт по домовете</Button>
                    </ButtonGroup>

                  <ButtonGroup color="secondary" aria-label="outlined primary button group">
                      <Button className="button">уеб графичен интерфейс</Button>
                    </ButtonGroup>

                  <ButtonGroup color="secondary" aria-label="outlined primary button group">
                      <Button className="button">уеб базирани приложения</Button>
                    </ButtonGroup>

                  <ButtonGroup color="secondary" aria-label="outlined primary button group">
                      <Button className="button">десктоп приложения</Button>
                    </ButtonGroup>

                  <ButtonGroup color="secondary" aria-label="outlined primary button group">
                      <Button className="button">видеонаблюдение 24/7</Button>
                    </ButtonGroup>

              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </header>


        <body className="App-Body">
          <Container>
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <ul class="list-group2">
                  <li class="list-group-item2">ИНСТАЛИРАНЕ НА ВСИЧКИ ВИДОВЕ ОПЕРАЦИОННИ СИСТЕМИ LINUX, WINDOWS VISTA/XP/7/8/10, MAC OS, СПОРЕД СИСТЕМНИТЕ ИЗИСКВАНИЯ НА ХАРДУЕРА.</li>
                  <br />
                  <li class="list-group-item2"> АБОНАМЕНТНА ХАРДУЕРНА И СОФТУЕРНА ПОДДРЪЖКА НА ВАШИЯТ ОФИС ИЛИ КОРПОРАЦИЯ.</li>
                  <br />
                  <li class="list-group-item2">ОТДАЛЕЧЕН ДОСТЪП ЗА РЕШАВАНЕ НА СОФТУЕРНИ ПРОБЛЕМИ.</li>
                  <br />
                  <li class="list-group-item2">ВЗЕМАНЕ НА ВАШИЯТ КОМПЮТЪР/ЛАПТОП ОТ АДРЕС И ДОСТАВЯНЕ ДО АДРЕСА СЛЕД РЕМОНТА.</li>
                  <br />
                  <li class="list-group-item2">ПРОЕКТИРАНЕ НА УЕБ ГРАФИЧЕН ИНТЕРФЕЙС ЗА ВАШИЯТ БИЗНЕС.</li>
                  <br />
                  <li class="list-group-item2">СЪЗДАВАНЕ НА УЕБ И ДЕСКТОП ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ СПРЯМО НУЖДИТЕ НА ПОТРЕБИТЕЛЯ.</li>
                  <br />
                  <li class="list-group-item2">ИНСТАЛИРАНЕ НА КАМЕРИ ЗА ВИДЕОНАБЛЮДЕНИЕ С ДОСТЪП ДО КАМЕРИТЕ ЧРЕЗ МОБИЛНИ УСТРОЙСТВА.</li>
                </ul>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
          <Container>
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <div className="App">
                  <form id="contact-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} method="POST">
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                      <input type="text" className="form-control" id="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.onNameChange.bind(this)} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="phone">Phone</label>
                      <input type="number" className="form-control" id="phone" aria-describedby="emailHelp" value={this.state.phone} onChange={this.onPhoneChange.bind(this)} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="message">Message</label>
                      <textarea className="form-control" rows="5" id="message" value={this.state.message} onChange={this.onMessageChange.bind(this)} />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                  </form>
                </div>
            </Col>
            </Row>
            </Container>
          <Container>
                <Row>
                  <Col>
                <MapContainer></MapContainer>
                </Col>
                </Row>
          </Container>
        </body>
      </div>
    );
  }
  onNameChange(event) {
    this.setState({name: event.target.value})
    }

    onPhoneChange(event) {
    this.setState({phone: event.target.value})
    }

    onMessageChange(event) {
    this.setState({message: event.target.value})
    }
  }


export default App;
```

I want to create a text file if not exists with .txt extension and every time when I have new inputs fields to be at the new line :(..

Comment: What have you tried? You need to show some effort

Comment: I update my question.. I see from this website: https://blog.mailtrap.io/react-contact-form/

Comment: But I want to save all input fields into a text file ?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense, I suggest you edit and try to form a clear question. Also please post your code and how you've approached the problem

Comment: Why ? I think my question is crystal clear... I just don't know how to create a text file and write into this file my input fields .... I really don't know what to do..

Comment: ReactJs is a Frontend library which means the code is executed in the client side, therefore it is not possible to save input data of any form into a text file, instead 1-you can take the input useing ReactJs, 2- Post the input to a server (With a language of your choice PHP, Node, Go ... etc) 3- write the data into a text file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The below snippet should give you an idea.

You might have to add a polyfill for createObjectURL depending on the targeted browsers.

```
  TextFile = () => {
    const element = document.createElement("a");
    const file = new Blob([document.getElementById('myInput').value], {type: 'text/plain'});
    element.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    element.download = "myFile.txt";
    document.body.appendChild(element); // Required for this to work in FireFox
    element.click();
  }
```

EDIT - 
You dont need individual functions for each input you can combine them into one and remove `onNameChange` `onPhoneChange` etc

```
  onChange(event) {
    this.setState({[event.target.id]: event.target.value})}
  }
```

place the onChange function *before* the `render()` function..

If this doesn't work please provide a reproducible link of your issue on codepen/jsfiddle etc;.

Comment: I update my question.. but I have too many errors like this:

Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application. Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};` class property with the desired state in the Wrapper component.

Comment: https://codepen.io/carlo-gambino/pen/JjYKmZE

I try to update my code but He's not work properly..

Comment: Should the element be removed from the dom after clicking it?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the values from the form and store into a file using following package:

### BrowserFS

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('/test.txt', 'Cool, I can do this in the browser!', function(err) {
  fs.readFile('/test.txt', function(err, contents) {
    console.log(contents.toString());
  });
});
```

Read more: https://github.com/jvilk/BrowserFS

Comment: Harvey, your solution requires Node, right?  I think Ben's original question is asking for a React-only solution.

Comment: No. BrowserFS does not require node and it does look great.
A problem with it is that it isn't React specific. Note that the original OP didn't specify it in plain words, but he did tag his question with react and gave a react example code. All in all this wouldn't be really a great problem.
The main problem that i see at this time is that this package hasn't been updated since 2020...